# Выяснение того, что не работает в Flash игре

Tags: отладка, flash

Есть сайт с Flash  играми. Поступают запросы,  что  игра  не  работает. Там  играет много иностранцев.

Как узнать,  что не  работает у пользователя, если:

1. Предложение по добавлению поля с описанием проблем  руководство отклонило
2. У меня все  работает, как на  основной OS так  и на виртуалке

---

UPD: Обновил вопрос, более конкретно

И как вообще диагностировать,  что не работает в игре стороннего разработчика?

Comment: А кто не хочет добавлять? Если юзеры, то они много чего могут не хотеть или советовать, а по факту готовое будут использовать совершенно иначе. Сделайте кнопку "сообщить о проблеме" в том месте, где нет флеша, ибо он может не работать. И запросы вам как-то куда-то поступают уже. Не очень понятно почему просто спросить нельзя при поступлении.

Comment: Ну так сказало руководство. Когда я предложил хотя бы добавить каптчу от ботов. Кнопка уже имеется. Добавил сам более точное  определение браузера, в основном  поступают от  хрома  на Windows Server 2008,  на втором месте Windows 8.1. Сам тестил, если флеш запускается, то игры работают.  В остномном  отмечают неработающими одни и те же  игры

Comment: это мы про тот флеш говорим, который последнее время на машинах сам запускает  деинсталлятор, и вроде прекратит работу 12.01.2021 ?

Comment: да, он самый...

Comment: Пока вы не получите описание проблемы, можно долго ломать голову. Некоторые игры могут не работать под определенным браузером, некоторые могут не работать т.к. у пользователя не установлен сам плагин (и устанавливать его сейчас огромная проблема и он может быть еще отключен принудительно). Можно конечно еще косвенно пытаться проверять статистику через JS (вообще установлен ли плагин) и свой SWF (работает ли он).

Comment: В  принципе это может сработать. У  нас есть свой прелоадер , в нем можно  проверять запустился ли  он и  загрузился ли полностью, и при отправке  запроса  добавлять эти данные. Спасибо, буду думать в этом направлении